# JSON, AJAX, REST Terminology

Tags: json, ajax, rest

Currently writing some documentation. Just wondering if we are using the terminology correctly.

We have an AJAX script that calls a service using a HTTP GET that returns JSON.

Would you call the service a REST service or a JSON service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call it a REST service which returns JSON.

**EDIT**

6 years on and what was I thinking! It's a *web* service which returns Json, as suggested in other answers. It may be RESTful, it may not.

Comment: a URI that responds to HTTP GET is not REST yet. Moreover, it's quite probable that it isn't due to not being able to guarantee what is expected of RESTful GET. [like preserving the state or not being resource intensive]

Answer (score 4):

Using HTTP does not mean you're automatically following the REST architectural style. If you don't know what REST is, you're pretty much guaranteed to not be doing it. Call it "a web service that returns JSON" instead.

Answer (score 0):

A client calling a service using an HTTP GET would not constitute a RESTful architecture. The following elements should exist for a service that has a RESTful architecture.

1. HTTP - used as an application protocol, not a transport protocol
2. URI tunneling
3. Hypermedia

So, in your scenario, based on the given information, your service can be classified as a regular service with JSON hypermedia or content type. It is definetly not a REST architecture.

Here are some additional information:http://goo.gl/32gLK